# Select rows in a self-relationship where all children meet a condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join, tree, self-join

I am working with a single table (called `documents`) with the following fields: `id`, `parent_id`, and `status`. The `parent_id` field refers to the `id` field in the same table. The `status` field is of type `ENUM('submitted', 'accepted', 'rejected')`.

I would like to select all `documents` that have **no** children where `status = 'accepted'`.

My first attempt looked like this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT `documents`.*
FROM (`documents`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `documents` children_documents
  ON `documents`.`id` = `children_documents`.`parent_id`
WHERE `children_documents`.`id` IS NULL
  OR `children_documents`.`status` != 'accepted'
```

The problem with this is that a document with both accepted and unaccepted children will still be selected. No document with **any** accepted children should be selected.

I have a feeling `GROUP BY` might be my friend, but I can't figure out how I would use it to get the intended result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `documents`.*
FROM (`documents`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `documents` children_documents
  ON `documents`.`id` = `children_documents`.`parent_id`
  AND `children_documents`.`status` = 'accepted'
WHERE `children_documents`.`parent_id` IS NULL
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the last line could just as well check `'children_documents'.'id'`. Yours is a more elegant solution, so I'm marking it as accepted. Unfortunately, I may end up not using it if my ORM library doesn't support multiple `ON` conditions.

Comment: Yes, in a left outer join, when there's no match in the table being joined, all columns from that table will be NULL, so you can check any of them. As a matter of personal style I like to use the one mentioned in the join condition. Otherwise, you have to watch out for columns that could contain an explicit NULL.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this with the [MySQL `CASE` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html).

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT `documents`.*
FROM (`documents`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `documents` children_documents
  ON `documents`.`id` = `children_documents`.`parent_id`
GROUP BY `documents`.`id`
HAVING SUM(CASE `children_documents`.`status` WHEN 'accepted' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

This selects all documents, regardless of whether they have children, and counts the number of accepted children they have. That number must be zero for the row to be selected.

**Edit:** For the curious, I managed to emulate the query in DataMapper ORM (CodeIgniter):

```php
$d->distinct()->where('status', 'accepted')->group_by('id')
  ->having_func('!SUM', array('[CASE]', '@children/status', '[WHEN]', 'accepted', '[THEN]', 1, '[ELSE]', 0, '[END]'), NULL);
```

Comment: @bluefeet: StackOverflow doesn't let you self-accept until two days have passed.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly what you're looking for, I would use the following approach to keep things simple.

```
SELECT *
FROM `documents`
WHERE `id` NOT IN ( 
    SELECT `parent_id`
    FROM `documents` children_documents
    WHERE `status` = 'accepted' );
```

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way in MySQL is probably like this:

```
select d.*
from documents d
where not exists (select 1
                  from documents c
                  where c.parent_id = d.id and
                        coalesce(c.status, '') = 'Accepted'
                  limit 1
                 )
```

This uses a correlated subquery to identify any children documents that fail the condition.

Comment: Are subqueries actually faster than joins?

Comment: @HenryMerriam . . . This variation should be.  There is no overhead of actually return data from the table.  In addition, when there are multiple matches, it should short-circuit the results and stop at the first match.

Comment: Looking more closely, I believe the status check should read `...AND c.status == 'accepted'`. (I'm trying to select the documents with no accepted children.) It's an interesting approach.

Comment: @HenryMerriam . . . You are correct.  Those nasty double negatives.  It wants to stop the first time it finds an unacceptable child, which would be one that is accepted.

Comment: In addition, since c.status is defined with `NOT NULL` (I know I didn't give you the table definition) could I get rid of the coalesce() call?

Comment: @HenryMerriam . . . Yes you can.  You have to be quite careful when dealing with NULLs in subqueries, so I tend to use COALESCE as a default.