# MySQL - How to select records that all child has status in ('A','B')?

Tags: mysql

For my question, I have 2 tables.

tb1 names Cases
tb2 names Calls

I have to select Case that all Calls contain status in ('A','B') 

Example:

Case A has 3 calls.
call A.1 has status A
call A.2 has status A
call A.3 has status B

Case B has 3 calls.
call B.1 has status A
call B.2 has status B
call B.3 has status C

So, query should be return Case A because in Case A all calls status is in ('A','B')

My query return all case record that contain call status not only A and B but also C. It's not correct

```
select  c.id
from cases c join calls ca on (ca.parent_id = c.id and ca.parent_type = 'Cases') 
where c.status <> 'Closed' 
and ca.status in ('A','B')   
group by c.id
```

Could you help me, please?
Thanks,
May

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Can you provide sample table data, and what you expect your query to return?

Comment: @shmosel I just updated more.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to find out how to make your question more readable and clear.

Comment: @SameerMirji Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this query to select case that all call is A and B

```
SELECT DISTINCT `cases`.id,cases.status,children.status
FROM (`cases`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `calls` children
  ON (`cases`.`id` = `children`.`parent_id`
  AND `children`.`parent_type` = 'Cases')

GROUP BY `cases`.`id`

HAVING 
    SUM(CASE `children`.`status` WHEN 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
and SUM(CASE `children`.`status` WHEN 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

[SOLVED] Please see link [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082353/select-rows-in-a-self-relationship-where-all-children-meet-a-condition) for more.

Answer (score 0):

```
select cs.*
from cases cs
join calls cl on cl.caseId = cs.title and cl.status in ('A', 'B');
```

Comment: This would return both cases, not only A

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. Nonetheless, I'll try to answer it:

```
select b.calls from tb1 a, tb2 b where a.status in ('A', 'B');
```

Comment: This would return all rows in b multiplied since there is no join condition between tables. Also the condition is wrong.